# Python - PIP : Is it possible to specify architecture?

Tags: python, pip, aws-lambda

I am building a Python Lambda function code to be executed on AWS (Linux).
My Dev machine is not Linux.
If I do `pip install`, I am getting Windows/MacOS related modules.

Is there a way to fetch Linux based dependencies always?  Such as a CLI argument for target architecture.

Comment: That's because python is supposed to be cross platform. Sadly, some dependencies use system-specific libraries and functions that limits their use on a small set of platforms (or a single one).
I advise researching your libraries, see what system they're intended to be used for and replace them with others to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks @catalin. I will explore this option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the exact same problem with Lambda, Python, and trying to get Pillow to work. After much searching around, I came across this article that explained the problem, and provided a great solution.

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/escaping-lambda-function-hell-using-docker-40b187ec1e48

Basically, you can run docker on your Mac, which allows you to run a Linux instance. Then using pip, install whatever library you want to use. You can then include those files in your ZIP file and upload it to Lambda. Works like a charm.

[These docker](https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda) images approximate the AWS Lambda environment pretty accurately. You can use them to create packages.

Comment: I was using the same for a while now. Forgot to update the post. Thanks @James Eberhardt